# How to debug through a cucumber karate project

Tags: cucumber, karate

I have inherited a Java / Maven / Cucumber project. I am fairly new to Cucumber.

Inside one of the folder I have a class like this...

```
import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Karate.class)
public class RoadsRunner {

}
```

Then in the same subdirectory / package I have a .feature file.
with a number of scenario's.

```
Feature: Check transaction
  Background:
    * url apiHost + '/api/v1'
    * configure headers = {'X-TransactionID': '#(Math.random().toString())' }

    Scenario: Get Classes
      # get classes
      Given path '/myUrl/classes'
      And param processName = 'myProcess'
      When method get
      Then status 200
```

Question One.

I am using Eclipse. Is there a way I can debug through the test in a similar way that I would debug a Java app?

I have downloaded myself the Cucumber Eclipse plugin but can't quite figure out how to use it.

Question Two.

Without using a custom plugin to debug is there anything I can add to the scenarios to maybe print extra debug information.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Cucumber Eclipse plugin](https://cucumber.io/cucumber-eclipse/) gives you 2 things:

- IDE syntax coloring / formatting support
- Being able to right-click and run a Feature directly without the JUnit "runner"

Karate is Java behind the scenes so you can debug and set break-points, but it may not be as seamless as you expect. In 0.6.0 you have the option of placing a conditional break-point in Karate code that runs before / after each test step - [see screen-shot](https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/902387883478097924).

So as you rightly called out, printing to the log might be the most effective way to work through complicated test scripts. Please refer to the [`print`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#print) keyword - which is exactly what you are looking for.

2 more points:

- the optional HTML report includes all [HTTP request / response logs](https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/899671441221623809) - which is great for troubleshooting a test.
- I would love for the [Karate UI](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-UI) (currently in alpha) to become stable sooner and be the best option for debugging, please do submit feedback and contribute if you can.

EDIT: we now have the Visual Studio Code IDE support with first-class debug support: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/IDE-Support#vs-code-karate-plugin

EDIt2: If you want to debug Java code, that is possible with the new IntelliJ plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19232-karate

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Debug-Server) here, At this moment best way to debug Karate Steps is using Visual Studio Code for developing tests and **[VS Code Karate Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kirkslota.karate-runner)** for debugging.

Visual Studio Code is Free, built on open Source and runs on all platforms including mac/linux and windows.

[Please note this](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-UI)

> The Karate UI has been retired and is not available in 0.9.5 onwards !
>   Use the VS Code Debug Support instead.

As per the comment by Peter Thomas, Eclipse/IntelliJ may also support debugging but I am unable to find any development there.

Comment: debug is possible only with the VS Code plugin. unless you want to put breakpoints in Java, which is not practical

Comment: with VS Code and karate runner with jar I can only put breakpoint F9 in java files not inside a feature file