# Is there a way to debug the java code in karate DSL

Tags: karate

I find it's very hard to debug when using karate DSL. The linked picture shows the html report of the scenario.

[image: 1]

Without debugging to java code, there's no useful info about why path statement was wrong.
Is there a way to debug the java code in karate DSL?

Comment: I guess you are finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46271703/how-to-debug-through-a-cucumber-karate-project) thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is an IntelliJ plugin that does this: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19232-karate

That said it sounds like you have some dependency conflicts. If you can replicate the issue in a quickstart project, please file an issue: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: It's hard to reproduce now.  when the issue occured, Runner.runFeature() was able to get the correct result with the same feature file.

Comment: I thought using Runner.runFeature() might be a workaround to debug the java code, though not quite the same as the run executed directly in the feature file.

Comment: The IDEA plugin can enable the java code debug.  However, when I debugged it , IDEA showed "Test framework quit unexpectedly", although feature file ran pass with a report. 
(The suspected dependency issue led me not to see it as the break point not hit when error happens.)

Comment: @GilbertGou I give up. please try to contribute, as this is an open source project